# Fixed-point iteration when image and domain are not the same

Tags: roots, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I have a function $f(x)$ defined on a domain $D$, but such that the image $f(D)$ may contain extra regions not included in its domain. I am interested in solving the fixed-point equation $x=f(x)$. If I do a fixed-point iteration:

$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$$

starting from a point $x_0\in D$, I risk that some point $x_n\notin D$ falls outside the domain.

Are there techniques to deal with such an $f$? For simplicity let's assume that $f$ is smooth in $D$.

Comment: Iteration makes sense only if $f(D) \subset D$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, of course. But in practice the situation I describe is not uncommon, I think. In reality all you need is that the initial point $x_0$ is such that the sequence that derives from it remains in $D$. Or somehow find a sub-domain $D'$ such that $f(D') \subset D'$. My question is computational. Is there a modification of the algorithm one can use?

Comment: Is it possible that $f^{K}(x)$ is a contraction on $D$ for $K>1$?  So one application of the map can introduce points outside $D$, but by iterating you eventually draw those points into $D$ and $f^K(D) \subseteq D$?  Then you can apply the standard theory and computational tools.

Comment: How exactly? I think $f^K(x)$ is not well-defined if some points fall outside $D$. At least not naively.

Comment: What is $f$, exactly?  Is $D$ just a Banach space, or is it also a vector space?  Is $f$ an operator on a function space, so you are getting functions returned that live outside the space of interest or something?  Perhaps you could extend $f$ to all of $R$ in a way that preserves key features of your analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of one such situation (of course there may be more—I only know of this one though): Browder’s demiclosedness principle. This states that if you have a closed, bounded, convex subset $C$ of a uniformly convex Banach space $X$, then any nonexpansive mapping $f : C \to X$ is such that $I-f$ is demiclosed at 0.

That is, we say a function $T$ is demiclosed at $y$ if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ and $T(x_n)$ converges strongly to $y$, it follows that $Tx=y$. In particular this tells you that $f$ will have a fixed point if $f$ admits an approximate fixed point sequence (which will occur if $f(C) \subseteq C$, for instance, which you explicitly say is not the case in your situation).

Here is a primary reference for this work if this at all resembles the kind of situation you might be interested in: “Semicontractive and semiaccretive nonlinear mappings in Banach spaces,” Bulletin of the AMS, by Felix Browder.

Comment: I just saw your comment above that your context is computational, which means that my answer is likely quite useless for your purposes. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks, its interesting nonetheless. Every bit helps.

Comment: Now that I’ve thought some more, I believe the notion of an “inward” mapping (or mappings satisfying so-called “inwardness conditions”) may be of use to you? I am not an expert on such mappings, however.